# R - Determine if a variable is a string

Tags: r, string, variable-types

Is there a way to determine if an R variable is a single string?
`is.character` looked promising, but there was one issue:
`is.character(c("a", "b"))` also returned `TRUE` which is not what I want.

Comment: One way would be checking the length at the same time.

Comment: Maybe `is.character(c("a", "b")) & length(c("a", "b")) == 1`

Comment: or `class(c("a","b")) & length(c("a","b"))==1`. Note there's no such thing as a variable in R really. `c("a","b")` is really 2 different objects in a function that prepares them for assignment to a vector or list, both of which are character, i.e. string.

Comment: ? both `class` and `is.character` are built-in. when would they not work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the comments, this is my current solution:

```
isSingleString <- function(input) {
    is.character(input) & length(input) == 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `is.string()` function from `assertthat` package.